# Why do I expect $\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Q(i)\otimes_{\mathbb Q} \Bbb Q(i))$ contains 2 points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is related to Iitaka's Algebraic Geometry Chpt 1, Sec 20, Example 1.27.

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Q(i))$ where $\Bbb Q$ is rational numbers. Then $X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Q)}X=\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Q(i)\otimes_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q(i))$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ If I am a normal person, I would expect fiber product of one point with another point over a point is a point.(i.e. If $X=\{pt\}$ instead and given $X\to\star$ map where $\star$ is another point, then $X\times_\star X=\{(\text{pt},\text{pt})\}$.) For the scheme category, this yields 2 points as can be seen $\Bbb Q(i)\otimes_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q(i)\cong \Bbb Q(i)\times \Bbb Q(i)$. Why does this happen or what is the intuitive reason that I would expect the fiber product have 2 points? It seems this is due to the fact that scheme category does not behave like set category or topological space category as it has extra information contained in sheaves.

Comment: From the algebraic perspective, the tensor product of a nontrivial field extension $k\subset K$ with itself, $K\otimes_kK$ is never a field, and if $k$ is perfect, this is reduced, so it's spectrum must be multiple points. The reason you would expect something like this is that the fiber product in schemes is very far from pullbacks in $\textbf{Set}$ or $\textbf{Top}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just not very accurate to think of $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Q}(i)$ as being "a point," for exactly this kind of reason. In this context a more accurate picture is that it's "two points related by a Galois action."

More generally, if $X$ is a scheme over $\mathbb{Q}$, rather than look at its Zariski spectrum we can consider the set of points $X(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, equipped with the action of the absolute Galois group $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. IMO this is a much more geometrically sensible notion of "point" to consider; among other things, unlike the Zariski spectrum it preserves finite products.

If we apply this recipe to $X = \text{Spec } K$ where $K$ is a number field, say $\mathbb{Q}[x]/f(x)$, then $X(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ consists of $\dim K$ points, one for each root of $f$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, together with the Galois action that factors through the action of the Galois group of $f$ on its roots. Since $f$ is irreducible this Galois action is transitive, and the Zariski spectrum can only see the orbits of this action, rather than the action itself.

I mentioned that this functor preserves finite products, so now let's apply it to the product of two copies of $X = \text{Spec } \mathbb{Q}(i)$. We can think of $X$ as being the two points $i, -i \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, related by complex conjugation. (Here I'm secretly thinking about the embedding of $X$ into the affine line given by the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$.) So $X \times X$ is four points $(\pm i, \pm i)$, which are divided into two orbits by complex conjugation: $\{ (i, i), (-i, -i) \}$ and $\{ (i, -i), (-i, i) \}$. Again, the Zariski spectrum only sees the orbits of this action, which is less information.

Comment: People think that the fiber product is mysterious but really it's more that the Zariski spectrum isn't very well-behaved.

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand the fiber product for affine schemes $Y=Spec(R),Z=Spec(S)$ is the affine scheme $Spec(S\otimes_T R)$ for some subring $T$ of both $S,R$ (more generally two subrings $T_1,T_2$ together with an isomorphism $T_1\to T_2$)

Here
$$X = Spec(\Bbb{Q}[t]/(t^2+1))$$

$$X\times_{Spec(\Bbb{Q})}X = Spec(\Bbb{Q}[t]/(t^2+1) \otimes_\Bbb{Q} \Bbb{Q}[s]/(s^2+1)) = Spec(\Bbb{Q}[t,s]/(t^2+1,s^2+1))$$
$$= Spec(\Bbb{Q}[t,s]/(t^2+1,(s+t)(s-t))$$

It is not hard to see that $\Bbb{Q}[t,s]/(t^2+1,(s+t)(s-t))$ has two prime ideals $(s+t)$ and $(s-t)$.

Comment: I could prove the fiber product of schemes in this case contains 2 points. Instead of proof, I am looking for a heuristic reason why it must contain 2 points from geometric point view. In other words, what makes fiber product of schemes in scheme category so different from topological fiber product in topological space category or correspondingly set category.

Comment: Were there any geometric explanations for such phenomena? Algebraic explanation is easy as tensor product of local is not necessarily local. Or consider $B_1,B_2$ 2 banach algebras over complex number and $B_1\otimes_C B_2$ as analogue. Now $B_i\cong C(M_i,C)$ from Gelfand-Naimak where $M_i$ are maximal spectrum. So the question is whether even $C(M_1,C)\otimes_CC(M_2,C)=C(M_1\times M_2,C)$?

Comment: Because the $\times$ doesn't mean product of set of prime ideals but tensor product of local rings ? $R \otimes_T S$ is universal for the bi $T$-linear homomorphisms from $R\times S$ so that's where we take the product of the fibers